# Summing rows based on keyword within index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, keyword

I am trying to sum multiple rows together based on a keyword that is part of the index - but it is not the entire index.  For example, the index could look like

```
                   Count
1234_Banana_Green   43
4321_Banana_Yellow  34
2244_Banana_Brown   23
12345_Apple_Red     45
```

I would like to sum all of the rows that have the same "keyword" within them and create a total "banana" row.  Is there a way to do this without searching for the keyword "banana"?  For my purposes, this keyword changes every time and I would like to be able to automate this summing process.  Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this:

```
df.groupby(df.index.to_series()
           .str.split('_', expand=True)[1]
          )['Count'].sum()
```

Output:

```
1
Apple      45
Banana    100
Name: Count, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the following dataframe:

```
raw_data = {'id':    ['1234_Banana_Green', '4321_Banana_Yellow', 
                               '2244_Banana_Brown', '12345_Apple_Red', 
                               '1267_Apple_Blue']}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data).set_index(['id'])
```

Try this code:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['extracted_keyword'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[1])
df.groupby(["extracted_keyword"]).count()
```

And gives:

```
                   id
extracted_keyword    
Apple               2
Banana              3
```

if you want restore the index, add in the end:

```
df = df.set_index(['id'])
```