# Sum column values based on part of index names in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe which is the result of a groupby operation.

```
Gender          F     M
Grade letter
D            NaN   1.0
D+            7.0  2.0
C-            3.0  2.0
C             3.0  4.0
C+            9.0  12.0
B-            8.0  10.0
B             6.0  3.0
B+            5.0  7.0
A-            7.0  4.0
A             2.0  4.0
A+            1.0 NaN
```

I want to combine grade letters like D, C, B, A ignoring the suffix (-, +).

The desired output is something like

```
Gender          F     M
Grade letter
D             7.0   3.0
C             15.0 18.0
B             19.0 20.0
A             10.0 8.0
```

I tried the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58082628/6814154), but it did not for me.

```
df.groupby(df.index.to_series().str[0]).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can aggregate `sum`, also for first letter is possible omit `.to_series()`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df.index.str[0], sort=False).sum()
print (df1)
           F     M
Gender            
D        7.0   3.0
C       15.0  18.0
B       19.0  20.0
A       10.0   8.0
```